# How to remove URL with error from the list?

Tags: python, html, error-handling

I have the list of more than 1000 URLs (those URLs are to download the reports) saved in a `.csv` file. 
Some of the URLs have `404 error` and I want to find a way to remove them from the list.

I managed to write a code to identify which URL is invalid (for python 3) below. However I don't know how to remove those URLs from the list automatically given there any many URLs. Thank you!

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
try:
   urlopen("url")
except HTTPError as err:
   if err.code == 404:
      print ('invalid')
   else:
      raise
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another list to save the 404 url(if 404 url less than normal url), then get the difference set， so：

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError

exclude_urls = set()
try:
   urlopen("url")
except HTTPError as err:
   if err.code == 404:
      exclude_urls.add(url)

valid_urls = set(all_urls) - exclude_urls
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider List A has all the urls.

```
A = A.remove("invalid_url")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError

def load_data(csv_name):
   ...
def save_data(data,csv_name):
   ...

links=load_data(csv_name)
new_links=set()
for i in links:
    try:
        urlopen("url")
    except HTTPError as err:
       if err.code == 404:
           print ('invalid')
    else:
        new_links.add(i)
save_data( list(new_links),csv_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError

# 1. Load the CSV file into a list
with open('urls.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    urls = [row[0] for row in reader]  # Assuming each row has one URL

# 2. Check each URL for validity using your code
valid_urls = []
for url in urls:
    try:
        urlopen(url)
        valid_urls.append(url)
    except HTTPError as err:
        if err.code == 404:
            print(f'Invalid URL: {url}')
        else:
            raise  # If it's another type of error, raise it so you're aware

# 3. Write the cleaned list back to the CSV file
with open('cleaned_urls.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for url in valid_urls:
        writer.writerow([url])
```